# Problem drawing dirtree

Tags: dirtree

I am trying to draw a dir tree using IEEE Access template but I keep getting errors. The problem is I have several papers only cited within the dir tree and I cannot take a snapshot as a result of this and the poor resolution. Any ideas on how to go about this. An example code using a dirtree is shown below

```
 \documentclass{ieeeaccess}
 \usepackage{cite}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
 \usepackage{algorithmic}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{textcomp}
 \usepackage{dirtree}
 \def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
 \begin{document}
  \history{Date of publication xxxx 00, 0000, date of current version xxxx 00, 0000.}
  \doi{10.....}

  \title{Preparation of Papers for IEEE ACCESS}
  \author{\uppercase{First A. Author}\authorrefmark{1}, \IEEEmembership{Fellow, IEEE},
    \uppercase{Second B. Author\authorrefmark{2}}}
  \address[1]{National Institute of Standards and 
    Technology, Boulder, CO 80305 USA (e-mail: author@boulder.nist.gov)}
  \address[2]{Department of Physics, Colorado State University, Fort Collins, 
    CO 80523 USA (e-mail: author@lamar.colostate.edu)}
  \tfootnote{This paragraph of the first footnote will contain support 
    information, including sponsor and financial support acknowledgment. For 
    example, ``This work was supported in part by the U.S. Department of 
    Commerce under Grant BS123456.''}

  \markboth
{Author \headeretal: Preparation of Papers for IEEE TRANSACTIONS and JOURNALS}
{Author \headeretal: Preparation of Papers for IEEE TRANSACTIONS and JOURNALS}

   \corresp{Corresponding author: First A. Author (e-mail: author@ boulder.nist.gov).}

  \begin{abstract}
    These instructions give you guidelines for preparing papers for 
    IEEE Access. Use this document as a template if you are 
    using \LaTeX. Otherwise, use this document as an 
    instruction set. 
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
    Enter key words or phrases in alphabetical 
    order, separated by commas. 
\end{keywords}

\titlepgskip=-15pt

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}
\PARstart{T}{his} document is a template for \LaTeX. If you are 
reading a paper or PDF version of this document, please download the 
electronic file, trans\_jour.tex, from the IEEE Web site...

%%%%%%%%%%%%%main part%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\Figure[t!][scale=0.5]{
\renewcommand\DTstyle{\rmfamily}
\dirtree{%
.1 Class1.
.2 Class2.
.3 Class3.
.4 Class4.
}}{Dir tree\label{dir}} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%end of main part%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\EOD




\end{document}
```

When I use the code below I get the second error

```
 \Figure[t!][scale=0.5]{
 \renewcommand\DTstyle{\rmfamily}
 \dirtree{%
.1 Class1.
.2 Class2.
.3 Class3.
.4 Class4.
}}{Dir tree\label{dir}}
```

The template can be downloaded from [here](https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-journal-article/authoring-tools-and-templates/ieee-article-templates/templates-for-ieee-access/). Also note that I put the dtk-logs [from CTAN website](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/usergrps/dante/dtk?lang=en) in the same folder as the tex file.

First Error

[image: First error]

Error after changing the main part

[image: Second error]

Comment: Can you show a complete example and also say which error you get? If I add your dirtree to the template I do not get an error.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for the comment, I updated the question.